# WAMP is running slowly on my PC

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I use the latest WAMP on Windows XP do develop websites locally.

Recently it has become slower and slower. Now web pages often take 3-4 seconds to connect before they begin to download and render.

Is there anything I can do fix the speed issue I am having?

Comment: Do you know exactly where is a problem ? PHP load slowly ? MYSQL slowly ?

Comment: There is a tool you can use to see whats happening (TCPView) `http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437` it will show you your tcpip requests, if you have a virus/worm you see lots of outgoing connections to different ips. you could also use in cmd `netstat -a -n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Clear your log files

I tried deleting my Apache/MySQL/PHP log files (about 200mb when totalled) and restarting the services.

Everything seems back to normal speeds now.

Answer (score 1):

is php loaded as an apache module? I vaguely remember having an issue with performance of my WAMP setup and it turned out to be somewhere along the lines of PHP not being loaded into memory only once but started up on every request. There's an option to configure how it's loaded somewhere in the httpd.conf... But it's been years since I had this issue... just wanted to add my two cents :-)